# Can I set a timer to a .vbs file?

Tags: vbscript

I have a 6 .vbs files. and I incorporated them into a file said as Main.vbs. Say

```
   Main.vbs

   Option Explicit

   A.vbs
   B.vbs
   C.vbs
```

So May I get timer count which will display the total time spent in the main.vbs execution?

A pop-up window will come to the user with only "OK" button, would display the time in mm:ss format.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StartTime = Timer
        //INSERT YOUR CODE HERE
Elapsed = Timer - StartTime
WScript.Echo Elapsed
```

Comment: @EI thanks for your quick help! Hope my post also will be helpful for others!! :-)